# Accessing external / non template / non angular2 element and reading its value with Angular2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-template

I am developing an Angular2 and integrating it with my ASP.NET MVC application.
To prevent CSRF attacks we have used Anti-Forgery Tokens in ASP.NET MVC helper function, which renders an input type inside the body.

Now I want to read this value and append it to the headers of all my ajax calls in my angular2 app.
I was not able to find a way how to read this value and pass to http wrapper service.

This is how the DOM looks:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="6fGBtLZmVBZ59oUad1Fr33BuPxANKY9q3Srr5y[...]" /> 
    <my-app>
    </my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is the way you should do it..

Comment: Why don't you http request the token and then append it on your future http calls?

Comment: assume you still want to do this, when you serve the index.html file, just insert it dynamically before sending it out

Comment: This is the way how CSRF is implemented in ASP.NET MVC application. It renders the input element and on successive postbacks it adds to the header. So does that means there is no way to access this in Angular2?

Comment: What can be a better way? I cannot get the token by a seperate http call as this call again will be without the token and which is unsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions everyone.

So here is what I did after researching and from all of the above suggestion.

I created a window-ref service that returns me the window object and also has the getToken() method.

Then I inject this service in my http wrapper service.

The window ref service has the getToken() method that will check if the document object is present and if it finds the element with the provided name "__RequestVerificationToken" it will returns its value.

If the element is not present then blank value or null is returned.

While in the HttpWrapper service I check if the returned value from getToken() is blank then don't append the "__RequestVerificationToken" header else append it.

I followed this https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/ link for the window ref service.

I did'nt wanted to make another call to get the token from the server, because this call would obviously wont have any security token attached to its request headers and this would have made this call unsafe. An attacker could have easily called this method and got the token and successively attached it to next calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with jQuery selector:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" id="input_element" type="hidden" value="6fGBtLZmVBZ59oUad1Fr33BuPxANKY9q3Srr5y[...]" /> 
    <my-app>
    </my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**Component**

```
checkValue(): string {
      return $('#input_element').value();
}
```

This is not the most elegant way to do what you need, but it is the only one, since angular doesnt allow access to anything outside  scope.
I actually used this to change css link in my  tag located in  tag.

**But**

Also consider the comments, that there is a better way to implement token based communication. You can actually save your token in localStorage after authentication procedure, or any other REST call. Take data from result of that REST call and localStorage.setItem('token', value).
You can create HttpInterceptor, custom one, where you can modify every REST call to have that token. Example of that:
https://medium.com/aviabird/http-interceptor-angular2-way-e57dc2842462